# html option tag using angularjs1

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hi i am new to angular and html. I am stuck with a small bug where in i have drop down in the html view with option tag inside select tag and i have used ng-repeat to show a dynamic array in that drop down everything works well, i have a condition were there is a text input box above my drop down with a add button so once i click on add button what input i have given in the text box should reflect in the drop down box with a select mark to that particular added input in the drop down if i click on the drop down box.

Here i have used ng-modle to save that input and ng-if to check if there is any input in the ng-model, even this works fine. The problem is when i select a value which is already there in the drop down that particular value is duplicated and added to the drop down with a tick mark.

Here is my sample code:

```
<select ng-model="newItem.Manufacturer" style="font-size: 15px; padding: 0px 25px;" class="form-control">
    <option value="">--Select Category--</option>
    <option ng-if="newItem.Manufacturer">{{newItem.Manufacturer}}</option>
    <option ng-repeat="abcc in addNewCategory" value={{abcc.Manufacturer}}>{{abcc.Manufacturer | camelCase }}</option>
</select>
```

addNewCatgory is the varible which hold the entire object.. from that i am taking only the Manufacturer and displaying it in the drop down. newItem.Manufacturer is were i am storing the newly entered value, newItem is already initialised in the controller.js file.

This is two line of code were i push the object to addNewCategory:

```
 $scope.addNewCategory =[];
    $scope.addNewCategory =  $scope.items.unique('Manufacturer');
```

[image: This is my output: Here i have selected Healthcare were that value is duplicated in the top with a tick mark]

Comment: Are you pushing newly  created object in addNewCategory array ? I mean how you are adding new value in an array?

Comment: Can you please add the logic you are using to push into the array?

Comment: Is duplicated because of your `ng-if`. Why is that there?

Comment: not able to understand, what you want to do...
If you want unique fields in dropdown then you can use $filter, its may be help you

Comment: i have attached only the drop down pic. there s a input box at the top were i am saving that typed value in newItem.manufacturer. so ng-if is for that if there is any value present in the variable show that option.

Comment: after adding ng-if to the option.. any itme i select from the drop down is duplicating like the healthcare in the above picture..

Comment: Not quite enough you have to put some code here.